# Error when subscribing to ERC-20 (BAT, i.e. Basic Attention Token)

Tags: web3js, erc-20

I'm trying to subscribe to BAT(Basic Attention Token) ERC-20 token "Transfer" event to detect any transaction made to my ethereum address using web3 in nodejs. I'm using parity (Parity/v1.10.6-stable-bc0d134-20180605/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.26.1) node running on same local machine -

parity --jsonrpc-hosts all --jsonrpc-apis all --ws-apis all --ws-hosts all --ws-origins all --ws-interface all

Here is the code that I've used to subscribe -

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const abi = require('human-standard-token-abi');

var contract = '0x0D8775F648430679A709E98d2b0Cb6250d2887EF'; //BAT contract address

var web3Socket = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://localhost:8546'));

function tokenEventListener = (address) => {
        let token = new web3Socket.eth.Contract(abi, address);

        console.log(address);
        let subscription = token.events.Transfer({
            fromBlock: 0
        })
            .on('data', (event) => {
                 // do something
             })
            .on('error', console.error);
}

tokenEventListener(contract);
```

I get an error when I run the code -
 Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node on WS

Comment: have you already a running provider ws://localhost:8546?

Comment: no sir there are no other providers running from my side. Is there any way of checking from parity whether or not a provider is runnig?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `--ws-origins` and `--ws-hosts` flags for parity. Try setting both to `all`.

Comment: I have made the changes that you mentioned, the issue still persists.

Comment: Try adding --ws-interface all.

You should provide more information regardless. Where are you trying to run the code (node, in browser?)? Is the parity node running on the same machine?

Comment: Parity node is running on my local machine and my code is written in Nodejs. adding --ws-interface all didn't solve it.